# how do I change the points on a star in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

how do I change the points on a star in inkscape?
im getting 6 points, but I want 5 point. on other computers with inkscape, I have 5 point stars. I looked in the tool config, but didnt see a way to configure it.

Comment: The number of points in the star / polygon is available [in the toolbar](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Shapes-Stars.html).

Answer (score 2):

[image: star image 1]

As shown in the image above, the stars/polygon tool is selected (lower left) and the 5 point star has been created. Above the star, you can see "Corners: 5" to match.

After performing other work, one can select the star created earlier, then the stars/polygon tool and edit. The image below shows that the previously created five pointer is now ten.

[image: star image 2]

If one pauses the mouse over the tool for stars/polygons, you see the keyboard equivalent, which is a star!  *